# Gatling to run scenario for each user/file

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am new to Gatling. So excuse me on my ignorance

I have the following code.

1. For users from 1 to 10, all the files in src/test/resources/data are posted using http BUT
2. I want to post one http request per file
3. Eg below there are 10 files in src/test/resources/data. So when I say
   `rampUsersPerSec(1) to (10) during (60)`  one file should be posted per user.

Any leads are appreciated. Thank you

```
  val httpConf = http.baseUrl("http://localhost:8082/")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")

  val files = getListOfFiles("src/test/resources/data")
  val scenarioOne = scenario("Post feature extractor")
                      .exec(
                         files.map( fileName => runFeatureExtractor(fileName))
                      )


    setUp(
      scenarioOne.inject(
        nothingFor(5),
        rampUsersPerSec(1) to (10) during (60)
      )
    ).protocols(httpConf)


  def runFeatureExtractor(fileName: String) = {
    exec(
      http("Extract features")
        .post("feature")
        .body(StringBody(fromFile(fileName).mkString)).asJson
        .check(status.is(200))
    )
  }
```

Comment: i don't think your objective is to idle the users. If you have only 10 files, then injected users should be 10. you can try constantUsersPerSec(1) during(10 seconds) or rampUsers(10) during(60 seconds)

Comment: @simpleApp - I want to post one http request (i.e 1 user ) per file. If inject user is 10 then it  posts 10 * 10 = 100 times. I want 10 * 1 = 10 times

Comment: rampUsers(10) during(60 seconds)  implies - I need 10 users and they should ramp up in 60 seconds. So users are still 10. this can be found in ` [##########################################################################]100%
          waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done: 10    

` other ways are atOnceUsers(10) or inject(constantUsersPerSec(1).during(10.seconds)) so it depends the use case you want to try. Pls note that if you are trying to look at Active users graph, then that tells you only active users, not the ones which already left.

Comment: @simpleApp - When I say 100 it is not 100 users. It is still only 10 users but for each user 10 times http post is called so 10 * 10 = 100. 
(as you see from above the my requirement is
 1. For users from 1 to 10, all the files in src/test/resources/data are posted using http BUT
2. I want to post one http request per file

So what ever condition is in setUp is applied to all the files in src/test/resources/data but I dont want that. 
)

Thanks for your time and effort. I think Gatling wont fit my use case.

Comment: gatling would be able to do that. post 10 files per user? is not ` files.map( fileName => runFeatureExtractor(fileName)) ` this doing that ?